# gcc -W warning flags

Tags: c, gcc

I'm learning C and in some examples I found "use gcc -W to enable warnings",

but reading the documentation here : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html

I can't find what -W do.

Can someone explain ?

I'm speaking about W and not w.

Regards,

Comment: You can always find the most up-to-date `gcc` documentation here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/

Answer (score 19):

`-W` is now deprecated by `-Wextra` with new `gcc` versions.

From `gcc` man page:

```
   -Wextra
       This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall.
       (This option used to be called -W.  The older name is still supported, but
       the newer name is more descriptive.)
```

Comment: Is -Wextra (-Wall + other options) or (options not in -Wall) ?

Comment: @Scooter `-Wextra` are warnings not enabled by `-Wall` so if you want warnings from both use: `-Wall -Wextra`